# How to close Bootstrap collaps after AJAX success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using a Bootstrap collapse control in my webpage. Whenever I click on the link it used to open and close. I am using AJAX to send data to a PHP page and on success print the result. After the AJAX call `data-toggle` should close. Please see my code below.

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#review" class="open-code btn btn-default">Write a Review</a>
<div id="review" class="collapse code">
    <form id="review">
      my code...
     </from>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', '#review_post', function(e) {
        //var $this = $(this);
        var message = $(this).find("#message").val();
        var rating = $(this).find("#input-2c").val();
        var vendor_id = $(this).find("#vendor_id").val();
        var infostring = 'message=' + message + '&rating=' + rating + '&vendor_id=' + vendor_id;

        if(message=='') {
            alert('Please add your Message');
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/review_vendor.php",
                data: infostring,
                success: function(data){
                    //alert(data);
                    $('#review_post').each(function() {
                        this.reset();
                    }); 
                    // here I want to use the code to close data-toggle

                    $("#flash").append(data);
                }
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();  
    }); 
});
```

I tried this code but it's not working:

```
$(this).find('.collapse').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the `collapse()` method on the `a` element again, providing `'hide'` as the argument. Try this:

```
$(this).find('.collapse').prev('a').collapse('hide');
```

[Collapse documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods)

Also note that you can make several small adjustments to your code to make it follow best practices. Here's a full example:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#review_post', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    var $this = $(this);
    var message = $this.find("#message").val();
    var rating = $this.find("#input-2c").val();
    var vendor_id = $this.find("#vendor_id").val();

    if (message == '') {
        alert('Please add your Message');
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/review_vendor.php",
            data: {
                message: message,
                rating: rating,
                vendor_id: vendor_id                    
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#review_post').each(function() {
                    this.reset();
                }); 
                $this.find('.collapse').prev('a').collapse('hide');
                $("#flash").append(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: not working i think .collapse is not the correct class. please see my html.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. You need to call it on the `a` element. See my update

Comment: Thank you for correcting my code but still its not working

Comment: can we use click event after ajax call click on the link. like that? i don't have much knowledge in ajax

Comment: You can, but it's better to use the methods the plugin provides. I made another change - using the `$this` reference inside the `success` callback, try that.

Comment: my data toggle is outside to $this. my form is in side the div.

Comment: Ah I see. In future questions please add a complete HTML example. You just need to find the right DOM traversal path to get to the `a`. If the form is inside the div, try `$this.closest('#review').prev('a').collapse('hide');`

Comment: you are awesome i got idea to make it work. i just added var parent = $('#review').closest('div'); and after ajax call parent.slideUp(300,function() {
     parent.remove();
    });